# How to set a system property from an android app?

Tags: java, android

I need to do `setprop` but from an app.

Right now I'm trying to just run it as a shell command:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "test:MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        exec("setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555");
    }

    private void exec(String cmd) {
        Process proc = null;
        BufferedReader successResult = null;
        BufferedReader errorResult = null;

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Log.d(TAG, "exec command: " + cmd);
        try {
            proc = runtime.exec(cmd);
            successResult = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            errorResult = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
            String s;
            while ((s = successResult.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "exec command: " + s);
            }
            while ((s = errorResult.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "exec command: " + s);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error running shell command:", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (successResult != null) {
                    successResult.close();
                }
                if (errorResult != null) {
                    errorResult.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error running shell command:", e);
            }

            if (proc != null) {
                proc.destroy();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This give me:

> exec command: setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
>
> exec command: setprop: failed to set property 'service.adb.tcp.port'
>   to '5555'

How can I set a system property from an application?

Edit: Sorry, I should have I added my device is rooted and this app is a system app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set this particular property from a regular app.
It is protected by the system.

Before Android 5, you need your app to have `sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in your manifest, and from Android 5 and up it needs to be `sharedUserId="android.uid.shell"`.

However, if your app has one of these user IDs, it must be signed with the system certificate to be installed, so you can only do this on development boards and custom ROMs.

Another option is if your device is rooted, you can run the setprop command with su.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that I am on a rooted device with a custom ROM. I'm doing this from a system app. So I just add `sharedUserId="android.uid.shell"`?

Comment: Depends on your Android version. If you are on Android 5 or higher, yes.
If you are on an older version like 4.x add sharedUserId="android.uid.system"

Comment: I'm on 5 or higher, but doing that isn't working. I still get `exec command: setprop: failed to set property 'service.adb.tcp.port' to '5555'`. How do I sign it with a system certificate?

Comment: If you have su in the system, you should just use that.
For signing, you need the key pair the ROM was built with.
Here is where AOSP stores their test keys:
https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_build/tree/master/target/product/security
It's the platform.pk8 and platform.x509.pem
If you don't have access to these keys for your ROM, you won't be able to sign the app